# How to get the HTML tags only from a string

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to get the HTML tag from a string with jQuery (or plain old JavaScript)?

#### Example:

```
var htmltag = "<table><tr><td>sample text</td><td><input type="submit" value="Click"/></td></tr></table>";
```

The output must like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Click"/>
```

How I can get the HTML tag from a string using jQuery?

Comment: wrap your string in jQuery object then use any transversal method on it

Comment: how can you give an example?

Comment: `$(html).find("input").html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the (as of posting this) highest rating answer in the [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)-Thread it might generally be a bad idea to parse HTML using regular expression. The thread has some interesting bits and pieces so if you are considering using a RegEx to parse some piece of HTML go ahead and read it. Quite a few cases are discussed.

In this example with the exact input from the OP given it does work. Using arbitrary HTML fragments would indeed be a bad idea. Just as an example consider having this field in your HTML `<input type='text' value='this is cool :>' />` it would totally mess up the parsing. (Even if it should be a &gt; ... this is the real world, don't expect it to be one). So be very careful and considerate about what you do.

My original answer was:

You could use a regular expression to match what you want. In this case it might look like this:

```
htmltag.match("<input .*?>");
```

The result would be an array containing just the input tag

Comment: *Never* use Regex to parse HTML, [lest you incur the wrath of Tony the Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Only use reg ex for html when it's very (*very*) basic html.  `<input data-brokenregex="<>"/>`  (update: ok: *Never*)

Comment: Thanks for linking that @RoryMcCrossan it was an interesting read and I updated by response. I'd love to strike-through my original answer but I have no idea how to do it with markup.

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your string in jQuery object then use any transversal method on it.

If you want the element as jq object:

```
var $input = $(htmltag).find('input');
```

If you want it as string:

```
var inputHTML = $(htmltag).find('input').prop('outerHTML');
```